# Object is not a function (evaluating 'function()') in react-native

Tags: react-native

I recently installed a package named 'trilat' via npm.

And I saw a warning after the installation of this package.
( which said I skipped optional dependency: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents)
and unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

I did not really care this err since npm installed the whole package.

But after I wrote a code using this package, I see an error message what looks like the question title.

It says that the Object is not a function (evaluating 'abstractMatrix()') and abstractMatrix is a function declared in the package.

I don't see this error occured due to the fsevent(which npm says it is supported in darwin).

here is the partial code related to abstractMatrix()

```
function abstractMatrix(superCtor) {
    if (superCtor === undefined) superCtor = Object;

/**
 * Real matrix
 * @class Matrix
 * @param {number|Array|Matrix} nRows - Number of rows of the new matrix,
 * 2D array containing the data or Matrix instance to clone
 * @param {number} [nColumns] - Number of columns of the new matrix
 */
    class Matrix extends superCtor {
        static get [Symbol.species]() {
            return this;
        }
```

.
.
.
and so on

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's a package issue. Ignore fsevents warnings. I would advise you to quickly post an issue in that package's repo on GitHub. It will be easier and solved quicker!

Comment: @ArchNoob I am trying to change all the require() to import. But I do not know what word should be in import XXXX from 'module-directory-name'.

Comment: Is that the same question or a different one?

Comment: @ArchNoob Same one.. that trilateration package is the only one which uses an algorithm that I want to apply.. So I am trying everything that I can to fix this problem before an update by a poster on Github. I think the source code from Github was for a react, not a react native. Is there a code which is valid in react but not in react native ?

Comment: @ArchNoob the package is 'trilat' on npmjs.com could you be so kind to check this package please..? I want to know that the package is usable in react native or not..

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to use this in the browser without browserify/webpack/etc,
>   include the dist.js file, which exposes the symbol trilat as a global
>   function.

Last words from the author of the project you are including from [this](https://github.com/JosePedroDias/trilat) repo here.

So, include the dist.js file from that project into your project *src* files, maybe even place it in your utils directory & import it in the files you want to use and use from there.

The project uses webpack/browserify and other stuff which I doubt are included in your build.